# Powershell couldn't execute a ps1 file in a full path in Cygwin of a Window Server

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a PowerShell script `newParams.ps1` in `/tmp` and `C:/` of a Windows Server which is installed CygWin environment.

The content of `newParams.ps1` is as below

```
##ps1_sysnative

function unquote ($string){
  if ($string.StartsWith('"')){
    $string = $string.Substring(1)
  }
  if ($string.EndsWith('"')){
    $string = $string.Substring(0, $string.length - 1)
  }
  return $string
}


Write-Output "Parsed params: "

$zero = unquote ($args[0])
$one = unquote ($args[1])

Write-Output "param0: $zero"
Write-Output "param1: $one"

# $Host.SetShouldExit(1002)
```

I can run it by

1. in directory /tmp

   powershell -inputformat none -executionpolicy bypass ./newParams.ps1 aba dfr > newnewnew.log
2. in directory C:/

   powershell -inputformat none -executionpolicy bypass ./newParams.ps1 aba dfr > newnewnew.log
3. in any directory

   powershell -inputformat none -executionpolicy bypass C:/newParams.ps1 aba dfr > newnewnew.log

But I couldn't run it by

```
powershell -inputformat none -executionpolicy bypass /tmp/newParams.ps1 aba dfr > newnewnew.log

$ powershell -inputformat none -executionpolicy bypass /tmp/newParams.ps1 aba dfr > newnewnew.log 
/tmp/newParams.ps1 : The term '/tmp/newParams.ps1' is not recognized as the 
name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ /tmp/newParams.ps1 aba dfr
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (/tmp/newParams.ps1:String) [],  
   CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Well, `/tmp/newParams.ps1` is not a valid path in your current environment, try to full qualify it, like: `c:/tmp/newParams.ps1`

Comment: Same issue.

But the file path is correct.
`$ ls -lt /tmp/newParams.ps1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 Administrator None 420 Nov 13 06:32 /tmp/newParams.ps1`

While c:/tmp/newParams.ps1 isn't.
`$ ls -lt c:/tmp/newParams.ps1 
ls: cannot access c:/tmp/newParams.ps1: No such file or directory`

Comment: try to add `-file`: `powershell -inputformat none -executionpolicy bypass -file 'c/tmp/newParams.ps1' aba dfr > newnewnew.log`

Comment: Thanks:) But it won't work, same issue. BTW, `/tmp` and `c:/tmp` are different directories with different contents in them.

Comment: hm, you could try to call Test-Path `/tmp/newParams.ps1` to validate the path

Comment: When current directory is `/tmp`, then what `Get-Location` return?

Comment: Does the account you are running it under have permissions to the folder, I think you also get an error like that if you do not have enough permissions.

Comment: @jisaak PetSerAl Test_Path and Get-Location doesn't support on the Windows Server.

Comment: @AlexisColes I am running as `Administrator`. The root cause is the nonexistence of `c:/tmp/newParams.ps1`

Comment: @WillZhou `Test-Path` and `Get-Location` is build-in PowerShell cmdlets how them can be not supported on Windows Server? What exact error you got when trying to use them?